# Find the $\angle DBC$ in the quadrilateral below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Given the quadrilateral ABCD such that $\angle CAD=25^\circ , \angle ACD=45^\circ$ and $\angle BAC=\angle BCA=20^\circ$ , what is the value of angle $\angle DBC$?

I made the drawing and distributed the angles.

I drew the perpendicular $CJ$ $\perp$ $JI$

I would need to demonstrate that $CJ$ is parallel to $BD$ and/or that $\angle CDB = \angle ICJ$ but I couldn't find the way

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, $E$ is a point on $CD$ produced such that $\angle DAE=20^o$

$ \because \angle CAE= \angle ECA=45^o$

$\therefore \angle AEC=90^o$ and $EA=EC$

Note that $BA=BC$, $\angle EAB=\angle ECB=65^o$ and $EA=EC$

implies that $\Delta EBA \cong \Delta EBC$ (SAS)

Hence $\gamma + \delta = \frac{140^o}{2}=70^o$ ----- (1)

Also $\alpha = \beta =45^o$

Since $\angle BAD =45^o= \alpha$

$\therefore A, B, D, E$ are concyclic.

Thus $\gamma = \angle DAE=20^o $ ----- (2)

(1) and (2) implies that $\delta =50^o$

Hence $\angle DBC=50^o$

Comment: I think in the 2nd line you meant $\angle ECA$ instead of $\angle ECD$.

Comment: @Hersh Thank you! Answer amended.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative short approach by slightly modifying the diagram you posted:

[image]

1.) Extend segment $BD$ to meet at point $E$ such that $AB=BC=BE$. Connect $E$ with $A$ and $C$. This gives $\triangle AEC$ and since $AB=BE=BC$, we can conclude that point $B$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle AEC$ and thus, via the inscribed angle theorem, $\angle AEC=\frac{\angle ABC}{2}=70$.

2.) We can see that $\angle AEC+\angle ADC=180$, therefore Quadrilateral $AECD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Using the properties of cyclic quadrilaterals, we can quickly establish that $\angle CED=\angle CAD=25$, this means that $\angle AED=45$. Since we know that $BC=BE$, this also means that $\angle CED=\angle BCE=25$, and thus, since $E$, $B$ and $D$ are collinear, $\angle DBC=25+25=50$.

Comment: Excellent. One suggestion: Once we have found $\angle BEC=25^o$, we can directly say that $\angle DBC=50^o$ because angle at center = $2 \times$ angle at circumference.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Correct. However since that would've required me to explain why $BD$ is also equivalent to $BE$ I decided to choose the alternative instead

Comment: @ Goku  The solution can be even simpler. Since you have proved that $B$ is the circumcenter of $\Delta ACE$ and $AECD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Then $B$ is the center of circle $AECD$. By angle at center = $2 \times$ angle at circumference, $\angle DBC = 2 \times \angle DAC = 2 \times 25^o = 50^o$